# Send email in background with auto dismiss of current view controller

Tags: ios, swift, email, mailgun

What I'm trying to do is send an email in the background from the view controller I made for song requests. I have it setup now but it just fills in the info from the textfields to the email but when you press the send button it opens the default apple email composer, so then the user has to press send again. I just want it to send directly from the view controller without opening the apple mail composer and also maybe have a alert that says song request sent and then dismiss to the previous view controller. I setup a MailGun account but can't figure out how to implement it. I've been digging around and trying different things but no luck. Please help. Here is the code to my song request view controller:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class SongRequest: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIImageView!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == nameTextField{
            titleTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else{
            titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            if textField == titleTextField{
                artistTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }else{
                artistTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return true

        }
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameTextField.delegate = self
        titleTextField.delegate = self
        artistTextField.delegate = self

        // Add gesture recognizer to dismiss view when touched
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closeButtonPressed))
        backgroundView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)


    }

    @IBAction func closeButtonPressed() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    @IBAction func sendAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailVC.setSubject("Song Request")


        let mailContent = "Listeners Name: \(nameTextField.text!)\n\n Song Title: \(titleTextField.text!)\n\n Song Artist: \(artistTextField.text!)"

        mailVC.setMessageBody(mailContent, isHTML: false)

        let toRecipient = "MyEmailHere@gmail.com"

        mailVC.setToRecipients([toRecipient])

        self.present(mailVC, animated: true) {
            self.nameTextField.text = ""
            self.titleTextField.text = ""
            self.artistTextField.text = ""
            }
        }
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot send mail through the user's email account without the user doing the actual send. This is per Apple's security policy.  If you want to use some other service, like this mailgun you mentioned, you need to rewrite your question to show your effort to try to get that to work.

Comment: "I've been digging around and trying different things but no luck." What have you tried? Please post the MailGun code that you've tried which has failed and we may be able to help. From the looks of it, you will have to call the MailGun API to send an email. Some googling also turned up [this project](https://github.com/KevinAo22/Mailgun-In-Swift) which appears to have implemented the MailGun API in Swift, so you might be able to use it or at least get some guidance.